# Error installing BEMCheckBox .fatal: unable to connect to github.com: github.com[0: 20.207.73.82]: errno=Operation timed out

Tags: git, react-native, github

[!] Error installing BEMCheckBox
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/Boris-Em/BEMCheckBox.git /var/folders/sz/vhtk6q413msg4zjtlyh0417m0000gp/T/d20230322-66604-3icq7t --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 1.4.1

Cloning into '/var/folders/sz/vhtk6q413msg4zjtlyh0417m0000gp/T/d20230322-66604-3icq7t'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 20.207.73.82]: errno=Operation timed out